# Magento 2.4.2 - Not able to get quote using customer id with cronjob

Tags: magento2, customer, quote, magento2.4.2

Not able to get quote data by customer id using `Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface` (method `getForCustomer`) with `cron`. Also tried with `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` with `loadByCustomer` method.

Working fine without a cron job.

Any solution?

Comment: Upload your full code what you have tried.

Comment: Fixed using Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation.

Comment: okay. But, without Emulation also it's return perfect output. I checked.

Comment: then post an as an answer. so other also know that.

Answer (score 1):

Need to inject in your construct `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory`

```
<?php

namespace RH\Helloworld\Cron;

class CustomCronQuote
{
    protected $quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',1); // pass your customer id
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Rohan.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info(print_r($quote->getData(),true));
    }
}
```

**Checked Magento Version : 2.4.2**

Comment: Also, require to add is_active filter, because there are many quotes for one customer in diff stores.

Comment: It's basic code. You can add filter and other points based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using `Emulation`,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation;

class File
{
    protected $emulation;

    public function __construct(
        Emulation $emulation
    ) {
        $this->emulation = $emulation;
    }

    public function FunctionName()
    {
        $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(1, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
        --- Your Code ---
    }
}
```